# Facebook SDK Auto Post #100

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, cakephp, facebook-php-sdk

I have problem with Facebook SDK auto post to my Facebook business Page.

It is working code but now it's showing me error

```
"(#100) Only owners of the URL have the ability to specify the picture, name, thumbnail or description params. FacebookApiException"
```

I create cakePHP script to auto post Facebook to my Page. I create new App -> I took App Id and Secret ID. I created Access Token with long time expired. Of course I verifed domain for my Page with bussiness acount on FB.

What is wrong...? I don't have any idea!

please find my code

```
$config = array();
                $config['appId'] = '16xxxxxxxxxxxx';
                $config['secret'] = 'a24faxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx';
                $config['fileUpload'] = false; // optional
                $link = SITE_URL.'/PostAds/details/'.base64_encode($post_id);
                $name = $this->request->data['title'];
                $price = $this->request->data['price'];
                $city = $this->request->data['city'];
                $fb = new \Facebook($config);
                $img_link = webroot.'/uploads/postAd/'.$image_name;
    $params = array(
                  "access_token" => 'EAACZA18CF5TcBAL0E4XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                  "message" => $name.' - '.$city.'  Price:'.$price,
                  "link" => $link,
                  "picture" => $img_link,
                  "name" => $name,
                  "description" => $name.' '.$price,
                  "published" => true
                );
                try {


$ret = $fb->api('/page-id/feed', 'POST', $params);


echo 'Successfully posted to Facebook';

} catch(Exception $e) {

  echo $e->getMessage();

}
```

Comment: Go check on the `ownership_permissions` property of the `url` object, to verify that you have actually successfully verified the domain. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/url

Comment: Thanks for your reply. How can i check on the ownership_permissions property of the url object, I have already seen this solution. but not know how to use

Comment: You simply make an API request as described there ... (Use Graph API Explorer to test it, then you don’t have to actually “program” anything for that. https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=%3Ffields%3Downership_permissions%7Bcan_customize_link_posts%7D%26ids%3Dhttp%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2F&version=v2.11)

Comment: CBroe . I have made a request using PHP crul for this ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts}. But same error after successful curl response